# Python EMA with Pandas over inconsistent timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to calculate the EMA over a given dataset housed in a Pandas dataframe. My desired alpha is 1 minute, so in a perfect world I would pass a span of 60 to the EWMA function.

Problem is, my timeseries is inconsistent - in the sense that it doesn't "smoothly" move from one second to the next. For example -

```
(Date | Value)
2015-05-27 05:14:35 | 5
2015-05-27 05:14:59 | 5.5
2015-05-27 05:15:30 | 5.2
2015-05-27 05:15:40 | 5.1
```

So a span of 60 obviously wouldn't apply here, as Pandas would just interpret that as every 60 datapoints rather than every 60 seconds. Are there any solutions beyond the obvious? The "obvious" being inserting datapoints for every second in the gaps, and extrapolating the values. I should note that the Date column is a proper Python datetime64 object.

My basic code...

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv("data.csv")
dfe = pandas.ewma(df, span=60)
```

Comment: You could add an ordinal variable for which group-of-60-seconds each row belongs to, then group by that ordinal value and apply the averaging function across the entire group, on a group-by-group basis. An easy way to do this would be to convert the datetime value to a number of seconds since the minimum datetime value, then do integer division by 60.

Comment: I think you want [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html#pandas.Series.resample)

Comment: How do you want to interpret missing data (seconds intervals when no updated values are received)?  Fill forward?

Comment: @EdChum yes, resample is it, thank you!

Comment: @Alexander, I'd like to fill forward. Trying to figure out how to do that with resample.

Comment: You should answer your question.. not edit the question..give yourself the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. @EdChum recommended the [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html#pandas.Series.resample) method in Pandas, and that is what I was looking for.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv("data.csv")
dff = df.resample("S", fill_method='pad')
```

The 'fill_method' option prevents the "new" values from being NaN.

So now a dataframe like this...

```
2015-05-27 05:14:35 | 5
2015-05-27 05:14:41 | 5.5
```

Looks like this...

```
2015-05-27 05:14:35 | 5
2015-05-27 05:14:36 | 5
2015-05-27 05:14:37 | 5
2015-05-27 05:14:38 | 5
2015-05-27 05:14:39 | 5
2015-05-27 05:14:40 | 5
2015-05-27 05:14:41 | 5.5
```